# file descriptor of a pipe in parent and child can also cause confusion

Tags: c

I wrote a program creating pipe passing message from parent to a child, I saw something different about the file descriptor:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int
main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  int fd[2];
  int read_number[1];
  int write_number[1];
  pipe(fd);
  int pid;
  if ((pid = fork()) >0){
     close(fd[0]);
     for (int i = 2; i < 5; i++){
         write_number[0] = i;
         write(fd[1], &write_number, sizeof(write_number));
     }
     close(fd[1]);
     //wait(0);
     printf("write finished from parent process:%d\n", pid);
  }else{// child process
     //close(fd[1]);
     int flag;
     while((flag = read(fd[0], &read_number, sizeof(read_number))) > 0)
        printf("The number is %d from child %d\n", read_number[0], getpid());
     printf("finished %d\n", flag);
     close(fd[0]);
     printf("child process finished!\n");
  }
  exit(0);
}
```

the comments are what I intend to do, for the read system call, from API, it will return success value or error value, success value could be n or less than n, or 0, error value is -1, but here something is quite bizarre:

```
root@Thomas-sun:~# ./a.out
write finished from parent process:29173
The number is 2 from child 29173
The number is 3 from child 29173
root@Thomas-sun:~# The number is 4 from child 29173
```

it means the child went out of the loop, but the child does not print the finish information;
whereas if I close(fd[1]) in child, then the result is pretty what I need:

```
root@Thomas-sun:~# ./a.out
write finished from parent process:31057
root@Thomas-sun:~# The number is 2 from child 31057
The number is 3 from child 31057
The number is 4 from child 31057
finished 0
child process finished!
```

if I did not close fd[1] in parent, I also get the following result:

```
root@Thomas-sun:~# ./a.out
write finished from parent process:31842
The number is 2 from child 31842
The number is 3 from child 31842
root@Thomas-sun:~# The number is 4 from child 31842
finished 0
child process finished!
```

So from the above result, it seems the fd[1] in parent will not necessarily work, what matters is the close(fd[1]) in child!, but why it goes out of the loop and do NOT print finished information?? thx for any shared idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

man 7 pipe says:

> ```
>    If all file descriptors referring to the write end of a pipe have
>    been closed, then an attempt to read(2) from the pipe will see
>    end-of-file (read(2) will return 0).
> ```

In your example code (after `fork()`), both the parent and the child process have an open file descriptor `fd[1]` for the write end.

If you close only the `fd[1]` of the parent process, there is still open `fd[1]` in the child process. So the write end exists, and `read()` won't return zero.

in the 1st log:

```
root@Thomas-sun:~# ./a.out
write finished from parent process:29173
The number is 2 from child 29173
The number is 3 from child 29173
root@Thomas-sun:~# The number is 4 from child 29173
```

The child is still running in the loop (`read()` is blocking) at background. And it won't print the "finished" log, if you don't send signal to it.

Comment: I've searched a lot over the internet, I never thought of blocking case, so as you said it will never receive even one byte from the pipe, even 0 and return, because parent closed write end and child does not close and has no chance to close, so it blocks and never return, thx for reminding me!

Comment: but for the last log, I'm unclear about it: I did NOT closed fd[1] in parent, but closed fd[1] in child, it does NOT block, and parent does NOT write to child, also flag is 0, but there is still reference to the pipe write end, this time, child is not in the loop, so cannot find answer!

Comment: @Thomas : In that case the fd[1] of the parent is automatically closed when the parent exits. What do you mean about: "parent does NOT write to child"?

Comment: here is the point, sorry to make you confused: assume wait(0) is uncommented, if I didn't close fd[1] at parent before wait(0), that means parent will no longer get chance to write to the child, in the parent the process is done waiting for the child to be done, but the child is waiting for any input...but read will not return any input...because no one is writing and there is still a reference to the pipe, do you get my meaning??thx for ur time!

Comment: write to the child means write to the write end of the pipe

Comment: Ok, I probably go the point. Write() calls are before wait(). So the parent writes numbers to the pipe. But wait() will block forever, if the child won't get end-of-file.

Comment: I test it again, and figure out it from you and the output, well, without wait(0) in the parent, parent will return automatically, and child will quit as well, and with wait(0) put in place and parent does NOT close fd[1], then child will never return, thx for your help!